# Title bar doesn't show in activity

Tags: android, titlebar

Title bar doesn't show in this activity can anyone check what is wrong

even when i put it in manifest file

android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.DayNight"

still doesn't work

activity_gallery.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_gallery"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
tools:context="com.example.kemo.cleantest.gallery">    
</LinearLayout>
```

gallery.java file

```
package com.example.kemo.cleantest;
    public class gallery extends Activity implements SimpleGestureListener{
        private SimpleGestureFilter detector;
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_gallery);
            ImageView imageView5 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView5);
            TypedArray images = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.loading_images);
            int choicer = (int) (Math.random() * images.length());
            imageView5.setImageResource(images.getResourceId(choicer, R.drawable.pic1));
            images.recycle();
            detector = new SimpleGestureFilter(this,this);
        }
        @Override
        public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent me){
            this.detector.onTouchEvent(me);
            return super.dispatchTouchEvent(me);
        }
        @Override
        public void onSwipe(int direction) {
            int choice;
            ImageView imageView5 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView5);
            TypedArray images = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.loading_images);
                switch (direction) {
                    case 
                       choice = (int) (Math.random() * images.length());
                    imageView5.setImageResource(images.getResourceId(choice, R.drawable.pic1));
                        images.recycle();
                        break;
                    case 
                       choice = (int) (Math.random() * images.length());
                       imageView5.setImageResource(images.getResourceId(choice, R.drawable.pic1));
                        images.recycle();
                        break;
                }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think your project style.xml change theme in parent attribute.@Gamal Aly

Comment: <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

Comment: Have you tried `extend AppCompatActivity`?

Comment: Yes@AshishSrivastava is right plz check @ AshishSrivastava  solution..

Comment: hehe thans @User6829548. Also make sure there is nothing that says `NoActionBar` in your `style.xml`

Comment: Thanks it's working with extends AppCompatActivity